# Nginx url rewrite stops going through location code

Tags: linux, nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I'm trying to configure my Phalcon (php framework) project on Nginx. Unfortunately I can't manage to make the rewrite work. In order to better understand my problem please check out the config file:

```
server {
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

index index.html index.htm index.php;
server_name 149.21.165.142;

root '/usr/share/nginx/www';

#custom settings for phalcon project:
location ^~ /phalcon{
    alias '/usr/share/nginx/phalcon/public';

    # if file exists return it right away
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # otherwise rewrite it
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ (.*\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        return 403 "Finally works.";
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/phalcon/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

#default project
location ~ (.*\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

`http://149.21.165.142/phalcon/` works great, but after adding any controller or action to url for instance: `http://149.21.165.142/phalcon/a` ends up with `No input file specified.`.

After getting to: `rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 last;` the parser stops going through the `/phalcon` location's code and jumps to location under `#default project` comment. Then as you can guess it does not find any index.php file in the main root path and the server returns `No input file specified` error.

Why rewrite stops going through the phalcon location? How can I fix that?

I hope that I described the problem well enough. Neither English nor Nginx are my strong points.

Comment: Take a look at try_files, that along with a named block would simplify the whole middle section http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: @Drifter104 I tried both `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` but in both cases it's running `#default project location ~ (.*\.php)(/.*)?$ {` and trying to open `/usr/share/nginx/www/index.php` instead of `/usr/share/nginx/phalcon/public/index.php`

Comment: When you use last it causes a new location selection to start. This time with `index.php` as the uri. This will then match the default project location